# How to apply media screen?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

I have two CSS files(desktop.css, mobile.css), one for desktop view and one for mobile view. Both works completely fine when run separately but as soon as I run them together using @media screen, the site messes up.

Here's the website.
https://assignment-b22c4.firebaseapp.com/

Here's the desktop.css
https://assignment-b22c4.firebaseapp.com/desktop.css

Here's the mobile.css
https://assignment-b22c4.firebaseapp.com/mobile.css

Comment: How do you run them together using media query?

Comment: Please read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428) and then provide a [repro] for debugging details!